# Negating Regular Expression used for a currency text field

Tags: regex, validation, input, regex-negation

I have a numeric text field that is used as an input for currency. I want to accept only numbers, and 2 decimal places, separated by a dot (".").

The user will type an amount, and dynamically a commission will be computed and displayed, without a form submission.

The proposed solution I came up with is to use this RegEx in the following manner:

`/^[0-9]+\.?([0-9]{1,2})?$/g`

`$input.val($input.val().replace(/^[0-9]+\.?([0-9]{1,2})?$/g,''));`

The issue with my proposed solution is that the RegEx that I used filters exactly the characters that I want to allow, so the expression should be negated.

eg.: `$input.val($input.val().replace(!(/^[0-9]+\.?([0-9]{1,2})?$/g),''));`

I have tried using negative lookahead but I did not managed to get it working.

I have a jsFiddle that might help with testing: https://jsfiddle.net/budxn9ey/

Please note that I need the RegEx to be negated, not the regex.test() method.

I am open to other solutions of course. For a better understanding of what I need, here is another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLr6h42p/

Comment: Don't fix input for a user, it leads to a terrible user experience because you **will** do it wrong. Use a library like imask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so the expression should be negated

[You are asking an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to "negate the regular expression" (that's a proposed *solution*), you're trying to sanitise the user input (that's the real *question*).

By the way, this should *probably* happen in the back-end, not the front-end, because front-end sanitisation an be easily bypassed by sending requests directly to the server. But ignoring that for now...

I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

```
$input.val($input.val().match(/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}/));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q1gdcz3f/)

Comment: You are right. It is just a proposed solution. I am trying to handle this in the front-end because I have a field that is dynamically generated based on the user input as soon as he types the first character. If it would have been for a form that was submitted, then yes, I would've done it in the back-end. As for you solution, I have tested the expression in the fiddle I provided, but it does not work as expected. I am updating my question now.

Comment: Ahhh I see what your issue is -- you want the text to auto-correct itself **as it's being typed**? In which case, my answer is *almost* correct, except that you do also need to consider `123.` a valid input (even though it's not a well-formed number), because it's a partially-typed number. So in that case, how about what I wrote above, but with the regex: `[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}`

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nLr6h42p/
The RegExp I provided filters exactly what I need to accept. So, for my proposed solution, the expression just needs to be denied.

Comment: @KashanNadeem Yep, and here's your updated fiddle with the one line of code replaced that I suggested above: http://jsfiddle.net/1bjarskc/

Comment: It works fine unless the first char typed is not a digit.

Comment: Ah... OK, you can actually just remove the `[0]` and this works as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/q1gdcz3f/ -- I've updated my answer.